# SSL certificate: “This Connection is Untrusted” notification when www added

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

When open my site in browser without www (https://nutritionmedicine.org.au/) it totally works fine but when i add www (https://www.nutritionmedicine.org.au/) the i got the "This Connection is Untrusted" issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the certificate of the site you will see:

```
Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=acnem.org
DNS:acnem.org, DNS:www.acnem.org, DNS:acnem.info, 
 DNS:nutritionmedicine.org.au, DNS:isnn2014.org, DNS:acnem.com
```

Thus the name nutritionmedicine.org.au is part of the certificate while www.nutritionmedicine.org.au is not. Which means the name in the URL does not match the certificate and therefore the certificate can not be trusted for the name in the URL.

If you want to access the site with https and the www prefix then you must create a new certificate which includes this name. No DNS aliasing, redirection etc will work.

Comment: Thank you Steffen, Just one more question is that a good idea to redirect "https://www.nutritionmedicine.org.au/" to "https://nutritionmedicine.org.au/" in .htaccess file? If yes how should it be done?

Comment: @Haroon: like I already said in the response: redirection will not work. You would also need a certificate for the domain you redirect from, which is exactly what you don't have.